# Writing to a file through a loop in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-io

I am trying to write a series of Strings into a file, Letters.txt.

```
 import "dart:io";

 main() {
   List letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"];
   File file = new File("Letters.txt");
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     file.writeAsString("${letters[i]}", mode: FileMode.APPEND);
   }
 }
```

When opening the file, `Letters.txt`, it should show "abcdefghij", but instead, it shows "j".  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?  I tried `FileMode: WRITE`, `WRITE_ONLY_APPEND`, and `WRITE_ONLY`, but none of those worked either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use

```
 file.writeAsStringSync("${letters[i]}", mode: FileMode.append);
```

or

```
main() async {
  List letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"];
  File file = new File("Letters.txt");
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    await file.writeAsString("${letters[i]}", mode: FileMode.append);
  }
}
```